# "same article alias" error in joomla when editing translated (joomfish) article in the frontend

Tags: joomla, alias, article, joomfish

joomla version 2.5.8
joomfish version 2.5.0

I have created an article and translated it with joomfish.
I login with the user that created that article and i'm trying to edit it.
In english(basic language) i can edit it successfully.
In greek(translation) i get an error "another article in the category exists with the same alias" when i try to edit the article.

Even when i put the translation in another category i am able to edit it once, and the new version is saved again into the category of the original article!!!so i can't edit it for a second time...

I could find nothing in forums and google generally...
Do i have to switch to the core-joomla-multilingual-system and uninstall joomfish? does it allow same alias in multiple articles?
Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar bug. This 'cause Joom!Fish 2.5 works another way then old versions. It keeps both articles (original and translated) in article manager, so articles anyway can't be stored with same aliases.

**What I did:** go to */libraries/joomfish/contentelement/contentelements/*
You can see *.xml files stored here. Every of this files is corresponding for different elements. For example open content.xml and find this code:

```
   <treatment>
      <target>native</target>
      <tableclass>Content</tableclass>
      <publishedfield>state</publishedfield>
      <translationObjectModel file="joomfish.translatable.translationobject.content">TranslationObjectContent</translationObjectModel>
      <jformModel>ContentJForm</jformModel>
   </treatment>
```

and remove this.

After you do this Joom!Fish stops duplicate contents, and you'll get many translations with same alias!

P.S.: You may need to remove duplicate articles in Article Manager.